# Why would I use ID in MySQL when I can search with the username?

Tags: mysql

In many tutorials about MySQL they often use an ID which is made automatically when an user has made an account. Later on the ID is used to search about that profile or update that profile.

Question: Why would I use ID in MySQL when I can search with the username?

I can use the username to search in a MySQL table too, so what are the pros and cons when using an ID?

UPDATE:

Many thanks for your reactions!
So let's say a user wants to log in on a website. He will provide an username and password. But for my code I first have to do an query to know the ID, because the user don't know the ID. Is this correct or is there another way to do it?

If I would store the ID of the user in a cookie and when the user logs in then I first look if the ID is the right one with the username. And then checks if the password is correct. Then I can use the ID for queries. Is that an good idea? Of course I will use prepared statements on all of this.

Comment: You can read the advantages and disadvantages related to surrogate keys on [Wikipedia - Surrogate key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key)

Comment: Thanks for that, do you have any idea on the update question?

Comment: When you insert a row into the database, you can get the last inserted ID. In MySQL you can user the `[LAST_INSERT_ID()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id)` informational function to get the newly generated ID. This means, you do not have to generate the ID prior creating the user, but you have to insert the user into that table which holds the key. BTW, if you have more questions, feel free to post it as a new question.

Comment: Ok, thanks for that,  but I meant the following. Let's say a user makes an account and logs in 4 days later then LAST_INSERT_ID() won't work. Is the use of cookies an option to get the ID directly from the user?

Comment: Sorry, my bad :) When the user logs in, it provides a username, you will check that name by retrieving the corresponding ID. You can store the ID in session and you can store the session id in cookie. Please search for these things on the  net. The topic is just too board for this site (specifically talking about it in comments)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From *"an ID which is made automatically"* I assume you are talking about an integer column having the attribute `AUTO_INCREMENT`.

Several reasons a numeric auto-incremented `PK` is better than a string `PK`:

- A value of type `INT` is [stored on 4 bytes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/storage-requirements.html), a string uses 1 to 4 bytes for each character, depending on the charset and the character (plus 1 or 2 extra bytes that store the actual string length for `VARCHAR` types). Except when your `string` column contains only 2-3 `ASCII` characters, an `INT` always takes less space than a string; this affects the next two entries from this list.
- The primary key is an index and any index is used to speed up the search of rows in the table. The search is done by comparing the searched value with the values stored in the index. Comparing integral numeric values (`INT` vs. `INT`) requires a single CPU operation; it works very fast. Comparing string values is harder: the corresponding characters from the two strings are compared taking into the account the characteristics of their encoding, collation, upper/lower case etc; usually more than one pairs of characters need to be compared; this takes a lot of CPU operations and is much slower than comparing `INT`s.
- The [`InnoDB` storage engine](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-storage-engine.html) keeps a reference to the `PK` in every index of the table. If the `PK` of the table is not set or not numeric, InnoDB internally creates a numeric auto-incremented column and uses it instead (and makes the visible `PK` refer to it too). This means you don't waste any database space by adding an extra ID column (or you don't save anything by not adding it, if you prefer to get it the other way around).
  Why does InnoDB work this way? Read the previous item again.
- The `PK` of a table usually migrates as a `FK` in a related table. This means the value of the `PK` column of each rows from the first table is **duplicated** into the `FK` field in the related table (think of the classic example of `employee` that is works in a `department`; the `department_id` column of `department` is duplicated into the `employee` table). Here the column type affects both the used space and the speed (the `FK` is usually used for `JOIN`, `WHERE` and `GROUP BY` clauses in queries).

Answer (score 4):

Please refer to [this post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/8334/why-should-i-create-an-id-column-when-i-can-use-others-as-key-fields).

> 1 - It's faster. A JOIN on an integer is much quicker than a JOIN on a string field or combination of fields. It's more efficient to compare integers than strings.
>
> 2 - It's simpler. It's much easier to map relations based on a single numeric field than on a combination of other fields of varying data types.
>
> 3 - It's data-independent. If you match on the ID you don't need to worry about the relation changing. If you match on a name, what do you do if their name changes (i.e. marriage)? If you match on an address, what if someone moves?
>
> 4 - It's more efficient If you cluster on an (auto incrementing) int field, you reduce fragmentation and reduce overall size of the data set. This also simplifies indexes needed to cover your relations.

Answer (score -1):

Here is one reason to do it from a lot.

If the username is really primary key for your relation using the surrogate key (ID) is at least the space optimization. In normalization process your relation can be splited to the several tables. Replacing the `username(varchar 30)` by `ID(int)` in related tables as foreign key can save a lot of space.